# How do I update GRUB with a custom kernel in Rocky Linux?

Tags: grub

On most Linux system, after update the initramfs (mkinitrd, dracut, update-initramfs...)
you "refresh" grub2 with this command

```
update-grub2
```

or this one

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and show me the new initramfs images..

Now this is what happen on Rocky Linux 8

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/rocky/grub.cfg 
Generating grub configuration file ...
done

grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg 
Generating grub configuration file ...
done
```

Generate it..but no images are read!

At reboot..

[image]

only the rescue image is seen!

How to refresh grub on Rocky Linux?
The answer `dnf -y reinstall kernel-core..` is not valid because this is a custom kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rocky Linux is designed to be compatible to the corresponding version of RHEL, and RHEL 8 uses GRUB's `blscfg` module, which looks into `/boot/loader/entries` directory for BootLoaderSpec files for individual kernels.

Basically, you'll want to write a file named `<machine ID>-<kernel version>.conf`, where `<machine ID>` is the contents of `/etc/machine-id` and `<kernel version>` is the version of your custom kernel.

The contents of the file should be similar to:

```
title <the desired GRUB menu item text here>
version <kernel version>
linux <path to the vmlinuz file with the "/boot" part omitted>
initrd <path to the initramfs file with the "/boot" part omitted> $tuned_initrd
options $kernelopts $tuned_params
grub_users $grub_users
grub_arg --unrestricted
grub_class kernel
```

See https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/BootLoaderSpec/ or https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/boot_loader_specification/ for more details, and https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/BootLoaderSpecByDefault for Fedora/RedHat-specific extensions to the specification.

Sadly, it looks like the documentation of GRUB's `blscfg` module within the contents of the RHEL 8 installation media is essentially non-existent. You have to know what to look for and able to go for external sources.